# error: class HackerRank is public, should be declared in a file named HackerRank.java

Tags: java

While submitting code on HackerRank, I am getting this compilation error:

> error: class HackerRank is public, should be declared in a file named HackerRank.java

How can I get rid of it? I have tried changing the name of the class to `main`, but still it gives me the same compilation error.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HackerRank {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException, Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int test = in.nextInt();
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (test < 1 || test > 10) {
            throw new Exception("Illegal test cases");
        }
        while (test-- > 0) {
            // System.out.println("Enter patient dna");
            String patient = in1.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            // System.out.println("Enter virus dna");
            String virus = in1.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            int l = virus.length();
            int i = 0;
            int count = 0;
            if (patient.length() > 100000 || virus.length() > 100000) {
                throw new Exception("Input length out of bounds");
            }
            for (i = 0; i < patient.length() - virus.length(); i++) {
                String sub = patient.substring(i, i + l);
                count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < sub.length(); j++) {
                    if (virus.charAt(j) != sub.charAt(j)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (count == 0 || count == 1) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this formatting? Use an IDE to format your code before posting - this is illegible.

Comment: remove the `public` prefix from class name

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please __format__, __comment__ and __explain__ your code. It's hard to read at the moment.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry new here.. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

Only one class can be declared public within a file and his name must coincide with the file name ( without the extension ).

Try renaming your file to `HackerRank.java`.

Alternatively, you can change your public class' name:

```
public class YourFileName{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually I have got the solution, HackerRank wanted it to be names "Solution".. 
Now am getting a runtime error while submission
that is:  NoSuchElementException: thrown at Solution.main(Solution.java:15)

Line 15 is 
String patient = in1.nextLine().toLowerCase();

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. As for a question-answer webpage, it is better to ask only one question per page, so the people that have the same problem find the solution they are looking for. If you have further questions create a new discussion and I'll be glad to try to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

Java requires that each public class have its own file, and that the name of the file match the name of the public class it contains. If your file is not called "HackerRank.java", try renaming it to that and see if your error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing may be for this two reasons

1. Your class HackerRank is public so may be your file name is not the same as your class name. Your file name must be HackerRank.java
2. Or may be you have two classes in the same file and both are public.

Answer (score 0):

Name your class as Solution, hackerrank provides an environment as specified in this [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment#!).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    ...
}
```